# How do I specify the account SID when creating a local group account?

Tags: windows, security, visual-c++

Is is possible to specify the SID when creating a new local group account?

I've successfully created a new group using the [NetLocalGroupAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370434%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function by specifying information level 1 (LOCALGROUP_INFO_1) but his creates the group with a different SID each time. This beahviour I expected.

What I would like to do is to specify the SID when creating the group account. It isn't possible to use NetLocalGroupAdd with level 3. So I moved to look at [NetGroupAdd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370424%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But this function creates a global group rather than a local one.

Is there a way to do this either during the creation of the group or update the SID with the desired one after the group has been created.

Comment: No.  Windows generates SIDs itself, there is no supported way to select or change them.  (Note that this is true for both global and local groups; NetGroupAdd ignores `grpi3_group_sid`.)  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that. Any SID generated on your particular machine is issued that machine's local security authority. (Okay, or the domain security authority if you're talking about a domain controller) That means, it will always have the form
`S-1-5-21<the machine LSA SID>-<random local identifier of the user/group>`.

This is because the structure of a SID is hierarchical. For instance, all SIDs under `NT AUTHORITY` have the prefix `S-1-5`, because that is NT AUTHORITY's SID. (e.g. `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM` is `S-1-5-18`) Your machine's LSA isn't allowed to issue a SID that doesn't belong under its authority, which is going to be the `S-1-5-21<random number generated when Windows is installed>` SID.

Answer (score 1):

No, the OS supplies the SID. The same is true of other identifiers like GUIDs. Generally speaking.

There are a narrow class of scenarios where the caller can supply these IDs, like during migration you can write SIDHistory, or if you use permissive add mode for GUIDs in AD. But generally speaking these things are frowned upon unless you *really* know what you are doing.

With more data about why you want this we might be able to suggest another path...